# Item by item scrolling in a WPF Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a listview which is quite small in height, but has 3-4 listviewitems which takes up the whole size of the Listview (so only one item can be displayed at once)

And if the user scrolls on it, the listview doesn't scroll 1 item at a time, it scrolls 2 items at a time (single scroll)

How would you set it so 1 scroll = one item down/up?

Hope I made myself clear with this, if not just tell me.

Comment: If you only want to display one item at at time then why a ListView?

Comment: I guess you want the `MouseWheel` scroll like when you click the ScrollBar up/down button.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're talking about the MouseWheel scroll here.

The *MouseWheel* scroll really depends on the `IScrollInfo` implementation. I suggest you to handle the *MouseWheel* event yourself before the `ScrollViewer` does. So basically, you could do something like following:

Handle the `PreviewMouseWheel` event on `ListBox`

```
<ListBox PreviewMouseWheel="ListBox_PreviewMouseWheel" Height="108" Width="100" x:Name="list" >
    <Button Content="Button 1" Height="100"/>
    <Button Content="Button 2" Height="100"/>
    <Button Content="Button 3" Height="100"/>
    <Button Content="Button 4" Height="100"/>
    <Button Content="Button 5" Height="100"/>
    <Button Content="Button 6" Height="100"/>
    <Button Content="Button 7" Height="100"/>
    <Button Content="Button 8" Height="100"/>
    <Button Content="Button 9" Height="100"/>
</ListBox>
```

In the code behind, fire the `ScrollBar.LineDownCommand` or `ScrollBar.LineUpCommand` when you scroll down or up.

```
private void ListBox_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Delta > 0)
    {
        ScrollBar.LineDownCommand.Execute(null, e.OriginalSource as IInputElement);
    }
    if (e.Delta < 0)
    {
        ScrollBar.LineUpCommand.Execute(null, e.OriginalSource as IInputElement);
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Therefore, you turned the *MouseWheel* scroll into the *LineDown/LineUp*.