# Listview - MouseWheel scrolls too many items

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple ListView

```
    <Grid>
        <ListView 
            x:Name="lstScreenshots" 
            Background="#303030" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=Screenshots}">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SelectOpenWindowDialog}">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="WhiteSmoke" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13" Height="30" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="3" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                        <Image Margin="3" Height="340" Source="{Binding Screenshot, Converter={local:BitmapToBitmapImageConverter}}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

where one items height fills exactly the window height. when scrolling down with the mousewheel, the displayed item changes from ie the first to the fourth row. how can I change the mousewheel's behaviour to only scroll one item

Comment: Duplicate of this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144802/item-by-item-scrolling-in-a-wpf-listview

Comment: @LeBaptiste: I stumpled over this solution before and implemented it. it is still jumping to the fourth element

Comment: It is a system setting, Control Panel > Mouse > Wheel tab.  Also exposed as the SystemParameters.WheelScrollLines property.  I don't have it set to 3, most other users do.  Ignoring the user preference is almost always a mistake.